# Laravel + vue-google-maps setup

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue2-google-maps

I'm trying to use vue-google-maps package with Laravel but with the most basic setup from the docs I keep getting the "[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?" error.

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
      key: 'MY_KEY',
      libraries: 'places',
    },
  });

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

** In my blade file**

```
<div id="app">
<GmapMap
:center="{lat:10, lng:10}"
:zoom="7"
map-type-id="terrain"
style="width: 500px; height: 300px">
<GmapMarker
    :key="index"
    v-for="(m, index) in markers"
    :position="m.position"
    :clickable="true"
    :draggable="true"
    @click="center=m.position"
/>
</GmapMap>
</div>
```

Note: I compiled my JS and it is referenced in my blade.html file.

Comment: did you try `<gmap-map>` and `<gmap-marker>`  rather than `<GmapMap>` and `<GmapMarker>`?

Comment: @CUGreen same result.

Answer (score 1):

The **vue2-google-maps** package does not automatically install all the components.

In order to automatically install all components you must explicitly set `installComponents` to `true`.

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'MY_KEY',
    libraries: 'places'
  },
  installComponents: true
});
```

https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/v0.10.5/src/main.js#L69